# How can I find the shortest path graph C# using microsoft.GLEE

Tags: c#, microsoft-glee

My project is to generate control flow graph from source code.

I generate it by GLEE. Now I want to find the shortest path in my graph.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Or read any documentation?

Comment: Clarified - hopefully - the question and updated tags.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Thanks for attention, yes i have graph in my code and i was read enough documentation , but i cant find any thing about path .